# How to fetch Review and Rating from Yahoo Local?

Tags: api, yahoo, yahoo-api, review

How to get Review and Ratings from yahoo local using URLs like `http://local.yahoo.com/info-11057512-gray-s-papaya-new-york;_ylt=AqfdTH3jqpVj68gKIK09u6WGNcIF;_ylv=3`.

Comment: its a real question i am searching about this problem since morning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution. we can fetch the review and rating from below url by passing businessid

Old: http://local.yahoo.com/rnr/getReviewNRating.php?bizId=1105712&mode=getReviews&rcnt=2&rstart=1&rsort=2

New: http://local.yahoo.com/rnr/getReviewNRating.php?bizId=11057512&mode=getReviews&rcnt=2&rstart=1&rsort=2

BizID has changed from 1105712 to 11057512

Comment: Is there any similar way to get the google plus reviews like

http://local.yahoo.com/rnr/getReviewNRating.php?bizId=1105712&mode=getReviews&rcnt=2&rstart=1&rsort=2

Comment: @designersvsoft: I am also looking for the same. If you get, please let me know also.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004406/how-to-fetch-review-and-ratings-from-google-local

Comment: I have posted the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004406/how-to-fetch-review-and-ratings-from-google-local/12136494#12136494

Comment: @Jitendra Pancholi: The above mentioned url is not working? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Vasanthan.R.P: Made a change in the solution, kindly have a look.

Comment: what is rcnt=2 rstart=1 rsort=2 here?

Comment: How to get the BizID and is it free...?

Comment: Its already present in the url after info. Check any review/rating url like  http://local.yahoo.com/info-11057512-gray-s-papaya-new-york;_ylt=AqfdTH3jqpVj68gKIK09u6WGNcIF;_ylv=3 Or http://local.yahoo.com/info-38029455-see-s-candies-new-york etc

Comment: I mean is there any api for yahoo local to show the business reviews to your site...

Comment: make an ajax request for the url http://local.yahoo.com/rnr/getReviewNRating.php?bizId=11057512&mode=getReviews&rcnt=2&rstart=1&rsort=2 and replace the bizId with your id and you will get json response with review/ratings. opne this url http://local.yahoo.com/rnr/getReviewNRating.php?bizId=11057512&mode=getReviews&rcnt=2&rstart=1&rsort=2 in your browser to see the json output.

Comment: Yes but How would I get the bizId...like in google api's first you have to do place search with string e.g. `PS%20Plumbing%20in%20Chicago` it will give you key for all the results for `PS plumbing in Chicago`...then You need to match phone no., street address(or whatever method you use) to make sure which one you were looking for and use that result's key to get reviews

Comment: http://local.yahoo.com/info-11057512-gray-s-papaya-new-york;_ylt=AqfdTH3jqpVj68gKIK09u6WGNcIF;_ylv=3 in this url, bizid=11057512 and http://local.yahoo.com/info-11146308-highbridge-swimming-pool-new-york in this, BizId=11146308. In each yahoo local URL, the number after the "http://local.yahoo.com/info-" is the BizId.

Comment: U are not getting me....I understand how are you using the business id in the url to get the data..but from where did u get these no. 11057512 and 11146308. for e.g If I want to get the reviews for `JS carpentry, California` and I dont know the bizID how would I get

Comment: For fetching review/rating, you must have to know these URLs, by just proving the name of a place, you can't do this. You have to save these URLs into your database first, then you can make an ajax call. Check the process of http://www.reputation.com/ or any other website for clarity like how they do it.